# Pourquoi le w est-il dit se prononcer en général /v/ et pas /w/ (oué) ?

Tags: prononciation, linguistique, éducation

D'après les manuels de CP que je vois, ainsi que plusieurs références sur le web, je lis souvent que le *w* se prononce « en général » /v/. Or, à part dans *wagon* et *WC*, la plupart des mots courants que je connais sont en fait prononcés avec un son /w/ : L'[OLQF](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2404) donne une liste de mots commençant par *w* par exemple et on voit que les mots prononcés /v/ sont nettement plus anecdotiques que les autres ; il ne reste pas grand chose (la prononciation de *wolfram* et *warrant* me sembe plutôt être en /w/ d'ailleurs). La liste des mots en /w/ est bien plus longue et comporte des mots nettement plus fréquents que *würmien* ou *wisigoth*.

La question est donc : pourquoi continuer à prétendre que la règle normale est /v/ alors qu'apparemment elle est plutôt /v/ ?

Comment: warrant se prononce normalement avec un *v*, c'est un anglicisme de le prononcer avec un *w*.

Comment: D’aucuns (notamment en Belgique) prononcent wagon avec un /w/ et WC /wese/.

Answer (score 8):

La liste donnée sur l'[OQLF](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2404) montre clairement des différences entre les deux listes :

À gauche, les mots semblent plus provenir de la langue française / allemande.
À droite, on retrouve beaucoup de mots empruntés à la langue de Shakespeare.

Web, water-polo, week-end, webmestre,... ces mots étant récents, on peut imaginer que cette liste devait être beaucoup moins fournie il y a quelques années.

Comment: On peut aussi noter que plusieurs des mots en /ou/ sont dérivés de noms propres anglophones (Watt, Williams, Wallace, Winchester, ...). À ce titre, il est normal que leur prononciation soit préservée.